# Resize an UIImageView to fit in screen

Tags: ios, swift

There is a `UIImageView` passed as an property through a segue from another view controller where the user has scribbled on an image. I couldn't fit / scale  the image to fit in a `UIView` in the receiving view controller. No matter what I try it goes over the screen.

Here are some I tried with zero success in `viewDidLoad()`

```
incomingImgView?.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.bounds.width  , height:  view.bounds.height)
// incomingImgView?.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100  , height: 100)

incomingImgView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

incomingImgView?.clipsToBounds = true

//incomingImgView?.frame = view.bounds
viewContainer.addSubview(incomingImgView!)


// incomingImgView?.image?.scaleImage(toSize: CGSize(width: 100, height: 100))
// incomingImgView?.layoutIfNeeded()

view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Comment: Why are you passing a UIImageView between two UIViews? Why not just pass a UIImage and let each UIView size things the way you want?

Comment: @CodeTree Please don't do something like that. Pass data around - not the interface.

Answer (score 2):

Please try this:

```
 incomingImgView?.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: viewContainer.bounds.width  , height:  viewContainer.bounds.height)
```

Comment: no :|

this is how it stands, but not working

     incomingImgView?.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: viewContainer.bounds.width  , height:  viewContainer.bounds.height)

            incomingImgView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit


             viewContainer.addSubview(incomingImgView!)


            view.layoutIfNeeded()

Comment: Please add  this line and try - viewContainer.layoutIfNeeded()

Comment: You can add constraint programmatically for incomingImgView with superView

Answer (score 0):

You are setting frame twice so the first time you are trying to set is replaced with frame  `incomingImgView?.frame = view.bounds` so it will take the frame of `view.bounds` and not `incomingImgView?.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.bounds.width  , height:  view.bounds.height)`.

Try the below code and check

```
   incomingImgView?.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100  , height: 100)
   incomingImgView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit    
   incomingImgView?.clipsToBounds = true
   viewContainer.addSubview(incomingImgView!)
```

Comment: sorry! that was a mistake while pasting the code, edited it, not working

Comment: @CodeTree Can you show me how are you passing the imageView from segue?

Comment: if let validVC: FinalViewController = vc {
            if let capturedImage = imgView {
                validVC.incomingImgView = capturedImage
                self.navigationController?.pushViewController(validVC, animated: true)
            }
        }

Comment: @CodeTree For better approach you should pass UIImage rather then the UIImageView.

Comment: as I said I have scribbling going on layers over uiimageview, so can't just take the image and need to pass the complete uiimageview

Comment: @CodeTree Do you mean that you are drawing something in image? or its a static image in your assets or coming from API?

Comment: I have got the thing working with by grasping the whole image using UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext and send it as uiimage.

Answer (score 0):

I've been working with this exact issue for a while and came up with this solution for the class that I have made which inherits from UIImageView (note that you can probably just place it as an extension of UIImageView itself instead of creating a new class if this is the only thing you're changing):

```
func scaleAndCenterInParent(){
    //Scales and centers to superview
    if let screenSize = superview?.frame.size{

        let frameSize = self.frame.size


        if frameSize.width > screenSize.width || frameSize.height > screenSize.height{
            //Image exceeds screen in at least one direction
            var scale: CGFloat = 1
            let frameRatio = (frameSize.width)/(frameSize.height)

            if frameRatio >= 1{
                //landscape frame
                scale = screenSize.width/frameSize.width
            }else{
                //portrait frame
                scale = screenSize.height/frameSize.height
            }

            //apply transform to self (imageview)
            self.transform = self.transform.scaledBy(x: scale, y: scale)



            //center
            self.frame.origin.x = (superview!.bounds.midX - (frameSize.width*0.5))
            self.frame.origin.y = (superview!.bounds.midY - (frameSize.height*0.5))
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: Note that you still need to set the .scaleAspectFit parameter, because this only changes the size of the frame. It retains the full image quality.

Comment: @CodeTree I'm sorry, that was a personal function, code updated now with:  self.transform = self.transform.scaledBy(x: scale, y: scale)

Comment: yes, although it doesn't make the view any smaller it scales to a bigger one, which would be very handy I guess where at least I can play... I will try and let you know.

Comment: @CodeTree This function only scales down if the view exceeds its superview (it does not scale up as it is right now). If you want it to scale up or down regardless of its size in relation with its superview just remove the if statement that checks if it exceeds the screen size

Answer (score 0):

have you tried `incomingImgView.sizeToFit()` This method fits the view to the correct size for its parent view.